# Declaring variables in blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined variable in blade template but it is not working. I am not getting any value of i. The column is blank.

```
<thead style='background-color:silver'><tr><td>S.N.</td><td>Name</td><td>Telephone No.</td><td>Mobile No.</td><td width="24%">Options</td></tr></thead>
<?php $i=1;?>
@foreach ($lists as $li)
<tr><td><?php $i++;?></td><td>{{$li->Name}}</td><td>{{$li->Telephone}}</td><td>{{$li->mobile}}</td>
<td><a href="{{url("/telephone/show/{$li->id}")}}"><button>View details</button></a>
<a href="{{url("/telephone/edit/{$li->id}")}}"><button>Edit</button></a>
<a href="{{url("/telephone/delete/{$li->id}")}}"><button>Delete</button></a></td></tr>
@endforeach
{!! $lists->render() !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will definitely work:

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
....
<?php $i++; ?>
....
{{-- This will output 2 --}}
{{ $i }}
```

Comment: what is wrong with mine? looks similar. nothing is displaying in that column.

Comment: @micky, you said that declaring variable in a Blade template doesn't work. I took your code, tested it and saying that it works. I've posted tested code.